# Understanding postgresql shared buffer reads and heap fetches for an index only query

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql version: 13.10 (AWS RDS)

Index only scan DB query

```
explain
  (analyse, verbose, buffers)
SELECT
  block_timestamp
FROM
  archive_tokentransfer
WHERE
  (
    from_addr = 72387
    AND block_timestamp >= 0
  )
order by
  block_timestamp
LIMIT
  10000
```

Query plan

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Limit  (cost=0.71..4279.42 rows=10000 width=8) (actual time=0.483..60.586 rows=10000 loops=1)"
"  Output: block_timestamp"
"  Buffers: shared hit=4909 read=1659 written=200"
"  I/O Timings: read=37.730 write=13.824"
"  ->  Index Only Scan Backward using token_transfer_from_addr on public.archive_tokentransfer  (cost=0.71..245647.39 rows=574114 width=8) (actual time=0.482..59.544 rows=10000 loops=1)"
"        Output: block_timestamp"
"        Index Cond: ((archive_tokentransfer.from_addr = 72387) AND (archive_tokentransfer.block_timestamp >= 0))"
"        Heap Fetches: 1145"
"        Buffers: shared hit=4909 read=1659 written=200"
"        I/O Timings: read=37.730 write=13.824"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=235 read=7"
"  I/O Timings: read=0.036"
"Planning Time: 29.771 ms"
"Execution Time: 61.209 ms"
```

last vaccum details

```
[
  {
    "schemaname": "public",
    "relname": "archive_tokentransfer",
    "last_vacuum": null,
    "last_autovacuum": "2023-10-19 02:51:55.087541+00",
    "last_analyze": null,
    "last_autoanalyze": "2023-11-06 18:53:41.891353+00"
  }
]
```

I am unable to deduce why we have to go through 6k buffers for fetching 10k rows for an index only scan.
Also, the number of heap fetches (~1k) seems high as we update very few rows in the table.

The index has 3 IntegerField’s(4 bytes) and 2 BigInterField’s(8 bytes) -> 28 bytes/row + some overhead.
We get an average size of around 50 bytes when dividing the size of the index by the number of rows.
As each postgres page is 8kb, we should have around 100 rows in each page even if we are assuming the pages to be half full. For 10k rows this should require around 100 page reads.

I tried recreating the index using postgresql `reindex concurrently`. There was no difference in the number of buffers read and heap fetches, but the size of the index did reduce from around 1200 GB to 850GB.

Also, we don't see a similar behaviour when trying different values for `from_addr`, even those having more than 10k rows. Their buffer reads are around 100 with 0 heap fetches.

I also tried deleting and reinserting the concerned rows - buffer hits reduce from 6k to 3.5k but the heap fetches increased to 10,001 from 975.

UPDATE:
Table schema

```
devapp=> \d+ archive_tokentransfer;
                                                          Table "public.archive_tokentransfer"
      Column       |       Type       | Collation | Nullable |                      Default                      | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------------+------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                | bigint           |           | not null | nextval('archive_tokentransfer_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 block_timestamp   | bigint           |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 value             | double precision |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 value_usd         | double precision |           |          |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 block_number      | integer          |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 tx_from_address   | integer          |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 tx_to_address     | integer          |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 emitting_contract | integer          |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 from_addr         | integer          |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 to_addr           | integer          |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 chain_id          | smallint         |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 tx_idx            | smallint         |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 type              | smallint         |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 pricing_strategy  | smallint         |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 token_id          | bytea            |           |          |                                                   | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "archive_tokentransfer_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "block_data_idx" btree (chain_id, block_number, tx_idx)
    "token_transfer_from_addr" btree (from_addr, block_timestamp DESC) INCLUDE (to_addr, emitting_contract)
    "token_transfer_nft_transfers" btree (emitting_contract, token_id, block_timestamp DESC) INCLUDE (from_addr, to_addr, value) WHERE token_id IS NOT NULL
    "token_transfer_participants" btree (emitting_contract, block_timestamp DESC) INCLUDE (from_addr, to_addr)
    "token_transfer_to_addr" btree (to_addr, block_timestamp DESC) INCLUDE (from_addr, emitting_contract)
    "token_transfer_value_usd" btree (block_timestamp, value_usd DESC) INCLUDE (from_addr, to_addr, emitting_contract) WHERE value_usd IS NOT NULL
Check constraints:
    "archive_tokentransfer_chain_id_check" CHECK (chain_id >= 0)
    "archive_tokentransfer_pricing_strategy_check" CHECK (pricing_strategy >= 0)
    "archive_tokentransfer_tx_idx_check" CHECK (tx_idx >= 0)
    "archive_tokentransfer_type_check" CHECK (type >= 0)
    "no_cross_chain_data_bt" CHECK (NOT chain_id = 0)
    "one_fungibletoken_only_bt" CHECK (NOT (token_id IS NOT NULL AND type = 4))
    "only_allow_token_address_types_bt" CHECK (type = ANY (ARRAY[4, 5, 6]))
Access method: heap
```

Comment: Could you please share the DDL for the table and indexes involved? (plain text, as an update to the question)

Comment: I think the only way to speed that up is to `CLUSTER` the table on the index.

Answer (score 1):

> I am unable to deduce why we have to go through 6k buffers for fetching 10k rows for an index only scan.

An index-only scan needs to consult the visibility map for every tuple. The pages of the visibility map are handled through shared buffers, and are counted in the buffer counts.  Every time a tuple is covered by a different page of the visibility map than the previous tuple was covered by, it will be counted as a buffer access.  Those accesses will almost certainly be hits, not reads (which is consistent with what you show).  There is no code to deduplicate buffer hit counting.  If there are 4 pages of the visibility map which get cycled through repeatedly, each time the "current" one changes it is counted as a buffer hit, even if it merely changes to what it was two changes ago.

> Also, the number of heap fetches (~1k) seems high as we update very few rows in the table.

For a table with a 850GB index, 1000 updates would easily be counted as "very few".  Maybe the few updates you do have cluster on that specific from_addr. But there is no point faffing about.  Just vacuum the table manually.  Either it will fix the issue, or it won't, and then you will know which one.

Comment: Interesting - You suggest that most of the shared buffer access is for the visibility filter with cycling. But, then, why do other addresses access around 100?

Comment: If other from_addresses are more clustered in the table, one visibility map page could cover all the rows which are needed.  Once that page is pinned, it would never need to be released in order to pin a different one, which means it would only count as one buffer access.